# Python: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'bye'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to write turtle code where something is triggered and the turtle window closes, so I try to use `turtle.bye()` but I keep getting the error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in 
__call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "E:\Home made game\Chapter 1 Log Cabin.py", line 346, in k1
    player.bye()
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'bye'
```

Comment: I just installed **turtle** and took a quick look. turtle.bye() and turtle.Screen().bye() don't work, but I never started a mainloop. Are you sure you started a turtle mainloop()?

Comment: Can you please post your sample code?

Answer (score 2):

`bye()` is a method of the Screen singleton instance, not Turtle.  It is also mapped to a top level function in the turtle package.  It will not work with a Turtle instance.  You can invoke it several ways:

```
import turtle

turtle.Screen().bye()  # not a turtle instance, the turtle package

turtle.bye()  # not a turtle instance, the turtle package

turtle.getscreen().bye()  # not a turtle instance, the turtle package

yertle = turtle.Turtle()
yertle.getscreen().bye()  # turtle instance gets screen singleton to invoke bye()
```

Once you call `bye()` the turtle world shuts down in a manner that's not meant to be restarted.